# Arabic Wordcloud not shown correctly

Tags: python, visualization, arabic, word-cloud

Months ago I generated a word cloud for Arabic text and it was working well. I used the same code now and the Arabic text is not correctly displayed as in the photo

[word-cloud error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyXZ9.png)

I tried different font types but nothing changed

Here is the used code

```
import os
from collections import Counter
import codecs
from wordcloud import WordCloud  
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt          
# -- Arabic text dependencies
from arabic_reshaper import reshape      
from bidi.algorithm import get_display  
#arb_stopwords = set(nltk.corpus.stopwords.words("arabic"))

rtl = lambda w: get_display(reshape(f'{w}'))
d = os.path.dirname(__file__) if "__file__" in locals() else os.getcwd()
f = codecs.open(os.path.join(d,"/content/drive/MyDrive/file.txt"), 'r', 'utf-8')
text = f.read()
COUNTS = Counter(text.split())
counts = {rtl(k):v for k, v in COUNTS.most_common(300)}


font_file = "/content/drive/MyDrive/NotoNaskhArabic-Regular.ttf" 

wordcloud = WordCloud(font_path=font_file,
                      width = 1000, height = 1000,
                      background_color ='white',
                      #collocations=False,
                      #stopwords = arb_stopwords,
                      min_font_size = 10).generate_from_frequencies(counts)
plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation="bilinear")
plt.axis("off")
plt.show()
print(COUNTS)
```

Comment: I would avoid using Arabic reshaper and the bidi package, these are hacks. A better approach is to install mplcairo and use this as the backend for matplotlib, which wordcloud will use. Mplcairo uses libraqm which in turn uses Fribidi or Sheen for the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm support and harfbuzz for complex font rendering. Mplcairo as a matplotlib backend provides support for matplotlib, wordcloud , seaborn and any other package built on matplotlib. I have a [Kurdish example](https://github.com/enabling-languages/python-i18n/blob/main/py/wordcloud_kurdish.py) on github.

Comment: I'm trying using molcairo but when installing mplcairo and PyGOpject I'm getting this error (note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  Building wheel for pycairo (pyproject.toml) ... error
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for pycairo
Failed to build pycairo
ERROR: Could not build wheels for pycairo, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects)

Comment: what version of python, and what operating system (and version) are you using?

Comment: Try running ` pip install -U wheel` first.

Comment: I'm using colab

Comment: ahh Colab, the error you are seeing can be resolved, but unfortunately I currently no of now way on current implementation of Colab runtimes to access the cairo surface. techniques that work on Linux, macOS, and Windows fail or are not possible in Colab. I am investigating approaches. But Colab has certain limitations.

Comment: Which environment you recommend me to use if I will use Anaconda for macOS

Comment: On macOS, I've used python virtual environments and pyenv, and mplcairo works fien for me on macOS and Linux. Haven't tried it in Anaconda, but should work if Anaconda doesn't have too many quirks.